# Links in “Recent achievements” are broken

Tags: bug, achievements-dialog

Here are my recent achievements:

> [image: recent achievements]

The first link is https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1429673/how-to-run-an-up-to-date-thunderbird-package-with-hdpiwayland-support-on-22-04/1431719#1431719

If I open this dialog on Stack Overflow, then the link is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429673/how-to-run-an-up-to-date-thunderbird-package-with-hdpiwayland-support-on-22-04/1431719#1431719

If I open this dialog from [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/tour), the link is correct: [How to run an up-to-date Thunderbird package with HDPI+Wayland support on 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1429673/how-to-run-an-up-to-date-thunderbird-package-with-hdpiwayland-support-on-22-04/1431719#1431719)

It looks like the link uses the **current domain** instead of the **domain name of the relevant website**.

I use Firefox 116.0.1 on [Ubuntu 22.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_22.04_LTS_(Jammy_Jellyfish)).

Comment: Or in other words, not using [absolute URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005079/absolute-vs-relative-urls)?

Comment: This was fixed today - see the answer to the duplicate.